# $xP(|X|>x) \rightarrow 0 $ implies $E|X|^{1-\epsilon} < \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Given $X$ is a random variable, and $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, prove that: 
>   $$xP\left(|X|>x\right) \to 0 \quad \text{implies} \quad \Bbb E|X|^{1-\epsilon} < \infty$$

I got a hint to use the Lemma: $$\Bbb E(Y^p) = \int_0^{\infty} py^{p-1}P(Y>y) dy$$ but have no idea how to continue the proof.

Comment: Are you expected to *prove* the lemma, or just to *use* it?

Comment: No need to prove the lemma, it can be used directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $Y=|X|$ is a random variable that only takes on non-negative values.  So the lemma holds for the random variable $Y$.

Because $\lim_{y\to\infty}y\Pr(Y\gt y)=0$, there is a $B\ge 1$ such that if $y\ge B$ then $\Pr(Y\gt y)\le \frac{1}{y}$. Let $p=1-\epsilon$. By the lemma, 
$$E(Y^{1-\epsilon})=\int_0^B (1-\epsilon)y^{-\epsilon}\Pr(Y\gt y)\,dy+ \int_B^\infty (1-\epsilon)y^{-\epsilon}\Pr(Y\gt y)\,dy.$$
The first integral converges, because $\Pr(Y\gt y)\le 1$, and it is a standard fact that if $\epsilon\lt 1$ then $\int_0^B y^{-\epsilon}\,dy$ converges.

To show that the second integral converges, note that
if $y\ge B$ then 
$$y^{-\epsilon}\Pr(Y\gt y)\le y^{-\epsilon}\cdot \frac{1}{y}=y^{-(1+\epsilon)},$$ 
and use the fact that $\int_1^\infty \frac{dy}{y^q}$ converges if $q\gt 1$.

Comment: Nice answer. (+1)